# How do I bower install Raphael.js?

Tags: javascript, raphael, gruntjs, npm, bower

I'm trying to install Raphael.js in my project in the most modular way possible. Raphael has a registered bower component, so that seemed like my best best.

With some guidance from the [Snap.svg readme](https://github.com/adobe-webplatform/Snap.svg) (which did eventually allow me to install Snap), I've gotten the farthest with these steps (starting in my project root directory):

1. `bower install raphael --save`
2. `cd dev/components/raphael/`
3. `npm install -g grunt-cli`
4. `cd dev/`
5. `npm install`
6. `grunt`

The last step appears to begin to build the component, but fails immediately:

```
Running "build:dist" (build) task
Warning: Unable to read "../eve/eve.js" file (Error code: ENOENT). Use --force to continue.

Aborted due to warnings.
```

The error makes sense, since there is no `eve.js` file at that path. I know that it's a dependency of Raphael, but where and how would I have installed that?

FWIW, I'm a bit green on bower & grunt, so I could just be missing a simple step. Unfortunately, an hour or two of experimenting and my best Google skills couldn't sort this out.

Answer (score 2):

I think, `bower install raphael` is enough. You don't need to build raphael, because bower already delivers the **compiled** `raphael.js` and `raphael-min.js`.